# Magento - Call Customer Account Menu in CMS Page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, menu

I have a cms page set in two columns with the left side menu where I would adding customer account menu in left bar. I tried to call `navigation.phtml` in `2columns-left.phtml` but I have only title "**My Account**" without links.

What can I do to get the customer menu links in my cms page ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show relevant codes. Without that, it is difficult to give you a specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add a snippet like this to your "Layout Update XML". You may update/extend/remove elements as per your will:

```
<reference name="left_first">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
        <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Wishlist</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="newsletter"><name>newsletter</name><path>newsletter/manage/</path><label>Newsletter Subscriptions</label></action>
    </block>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
    <block type="sales/reorder_sidebar" name="sale.reorder.sidebar" template="sales/reorder/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Example from backend:
[image]

The layouts itself are located at app/design/frontend/base/default/layout (respectively at `app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/layout`).